# How to turn Flask Response Object into Dictionary

Tags: python, json, dictionary, flask

I understand that flask.jsonify returns a flask Response object. However I can't figure out how to convert this object into a dictionary. How would I go about doing this?

```
@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def hello(): #Accept and jsonify GET request from Nexmo
    if request.method == 'GET':
        info = jsonify(request.args.lists())
        #Turn info into dictionary here
        process(info)
        return info
    else:
        return 'Hello World!'
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`requests.args` is already a dictionary-like object, a [MultiDict](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict).  You do not need to use `jsonify` on it first.

You should just call `process` with `request.args` directly.

If you really want a dict, you can call [`request.args.to_dict(flat=False)`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/datastructures/#werkzeug.datastructures.MultiDict.to_dict).